# Do I need to synchronize writes to memory mapped file from different threads before flushing and unmapping it?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, atomic, mmap, memory-mapped-files

Let suppose I have memory mapped file and write into it from different threads (writes never overlap and are independent from each other). I want to sync already written data with disk and execute [`msync`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msync.2.html) or [`FlushViewOfFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-flushviewoffile), then unmap file.

Do I need to synchronize writer threads with flushing thread, e.g. using release memory fences on writers and acquire fences on a flusher? I fear that some of the writes would still be in the CPU caches and not in main memory at this point.

Do CPU and OS guarantee that writes that are still on CPU caches would eventually get into disk or should I first ensure that writes reach main RAM and only then flush and unmap a file?

My threads don't ever read from mapped pages and I want to use only relaxed atomic operations to track my data, if that is possible.

Pseudo-code of what I try to do:

```c
static NUM_WRITERS: AtomicUint = 0;
static CURRENT_OFFSET: AtomicUint = 0;

fn some_thread_fn(void* buffer, payload: &[byte]){
   NUM_WRITERS.fetch_add(1, memory_order_relaxed);
   offset = CURRENT_OFFSET.fetch_add(payload_size, memory_order_relaxed);
   void* dst = buffer + offset;
   memcpy(dst, payload, payload_size);
   
   // Do I need memory fence or fetch_sub(Release) here?
   compiler_fence(memory_order_release); // Prevent compiler from reordering instructions
   NUM_WRITERS.fetch_sub(1, memory_order_relaxed);

   if offset + payload_size < buffer_size {
      // Some other thread is responsible for unmapping.
      return;
   }

   while (NUM_WRITERS.load(relaxed) > 0) {
      mm_pause();
   }

   // Do I need acquire memory fence here?
   compiler_fence(memory_order_acquire); // Prevent compiler from reordering instructions
   flush_async(buffer);
   unmap(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Instead of a spinloop, consider using wait/notify so that you don't waste CPU time.  `mm_pause()` may relax CPU power consumption, but it doesn't yield to the OS to let other processes use the CPU.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, I know but I didn't want to overload my example with details. My question is about memory order and mmap with conjunction with threads, not about how optimally do my thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All stores need to happen-before the `munmap`, else they could fault.  They will make it to disk unless the system crashes before that happens.  For data to be affected by `msync`, make sure the write (assignments / memcpy) happens-before `msync` on that address range.

`fdatasync` on the fd after `munmap` would be a simpler way to make sure all dirty data makes it to disk ASAP, unless you have other regions of the file that you *don't* want to sync.  Without any manual syncing, dirty pages in the page-cache get queued for write back to disk after some timeout, like 15 seconds.

**Sequenced-before is a sufficiently-strong form of happens-before,** since a call to `munmap` or `mysnc` does the "observing" from this thread.  For example, within a single thread, the "dirty" flag bits in the page-table entries *will* be seen by any later kernel code (such as during the `msync` syscall) for pages modified by store instructions by this thread.  (Or by any other threads that you've synced-with.)

I think in your case, yes you do need `NUM_WRITERS.fetch_sub(1, memory_order_release);` for every thread, and `while (NUM_WRITERS.load(acquire) > 0) { pause }` for the one thread that reaches that spin-wait loop to do the cleanup.  `mm_pause()` is x86-specific; on x86, `acquire` loads are free, same asm as `relaxed`.  And all RMWs need `lock`, e.g. `lock add`, the same asm that's strong enough for `seq_cst`.  If you plan to port to other ISAs, then rest assured AArch64 has relatively efficient `acquire` and `release`.

`relaxed` may work most of the time, but would in theory allow this thread to `munmap` and invalidate the page-table entries before other threads have even reached the store instructions, leading to a fault.  Or more plausibly to have some of the stores happen after `mysnc`.

With cache-coherent DMA (like on x86), only the actual DMA read of the memory by the device is the deadline for stores to have committed to cache.  (But for `msync` to notice the page was dirty in the first place and queue it for writing to disk, at least one byte of it would have to be written recently before the OS checked the hardware page tables.)

When a store instruction runs on a page where the TLB entry shows the `D` (Dirty) bit = 0, on x86 that core takes a microcode assist to atomically RMW the page-table entry to have `D=1`.  (https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging#Page_Directory)  There's also an `A` bit which gets set even by reads.  (The OS can clear this and see which pages have it set again soon; those pages are bad choices for eviction.)

---

You don't need manual `atomic_signal_fence` (aka `compiler_barrier`) because compilers already can't move stores past a function call to a function that might read the stored data.  (Like `arr[i] = 1; foo(arr)` where `foo` is `msync` or `munmap`, for exactly the same reason it's safe with a user-defined function the CPU doesn't know about.)  CPUs that do out-of-order exec will preserve the illusion of a single thread running in program order.

---

If each write has page granularity, you could have each thread do its own `msync` on the pages it wrote.  This would be not great if writes are smaller than pages, since you'd trigger multiple disk I/Os for the same page, though.